# Kotlin coroutines not downloading data

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I am using Kotlin corountines in my Android Project. I am trying to download some data and display in a textview.

Following is my code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tv.setOnClickListener {
            downloadData()
        }
    }


    private fun downloadData() {

        runBlocking {
            pb_activity_main.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            var data = ""
            async {
                data = downloadDataBlocking()
            }.await()
            tv.text = data
            pb_activity_main.visibility = View.GONE

        }
    }


    private fun downloadDataBlocking(): String {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").build()
        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
        return response.body()?.string() ?: ""
    }
}
```

But the data is not downloaded. I am not able to figure out why.

I have included the internet permission in Manifest and the url is also working.

Comment: This not an effective use of coroutines, all you're doing is running blocking code.

Comment: @Minn i am not able to access the launch or async method of coroutines with writing them inside runBlocking.

Comment: The problem is that you're calling a blocking I/O operation inside the coroutine which then in turn blocks the coroutine dispatcher from doing anything else. This means you effectively slow down everything that would run on that dispatcher making it a bad use of coroutines. Additionally you use `runBlocking` and immediately await your coroutine so that is essentially just a normal function without any concurrency.

Comment: @Minn then how to access launch and async without runBlocking in Android Project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tv.setOnClickListener {
            downloadData()
        }
    }


    private fun downloadData() {
        launch {
            pb_activity_main.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tv.text = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { downloadDataBlocking() }
            pb_activity_main.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }


    private fun downloadDataBlocking(): String {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").build()
        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
        return response.body()?.string() ?: ""
    }
}
```

First: you should **never use `runBLocking`** out of unit-testing or other special domain.

> [This function](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) should not be used from coroutine. It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests.

Second:

> [Coroutines are always related to some local scope in your application](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952), which is an entity with a limited life-time, [like a UI element](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html).

That's why `Activity` implements `CoroutineScope`. Honestly, a better place for it is `ViewModel` or `Presenter`, but I don't see any in the code...

Third, it is quite pointless to use`async` and `await` right after it's definition. Just use `withContext` then.

Comment: Make sure you're also extending the CoroutineScope and you're importing the launch function

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin I am not sure. I am not getting any useful logs

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin Yes. The app keeps showing the progressbar. I have copy pasted your code. I have included internet permission